# Why does Maleficent take care of Aurora?

Tags: plot-explanation, maleficent

In *Maleficent* (2014), why does Maleficent suddenly care about Aurora?

It first happens when Aurora is still a baby and she was hungry, Maleficent feeds her.

Is it some kind of weird effect from when she curse her and then she suddenly care about her.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are asking. Do you mean why does she take care of her at the christening or Aurora is grown? If the latter that's clearly explained/cover in the movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Because Maleficent is not actually evil.*

Her bad deeds were a direct result of her reaction to Stefan's betrayal of her. She followed Aurora's life to revel in her "ingenious" revenge. Maleficent kept Aurora safe initially (feeding her and keeping her from falling off a cliff) so that she could continue to enjoy her plan.

Of course, over time her normal, loving personality became dominant, and she wished she had never cursed Aurora. She tried to reverse it. Eventually, her guilt and love drove her to make Aurora the center of her life. Another factor would be that Aurora was given the magical gifts of being happy and pretty (well liked by others).